# How to find overlapped points in postGIS

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, postgis

I have a set of point dataset in postgis with xcoordinate and ycordinate. There are few points which overlapped with each other as they are having same xcoordinate and ycoordniate. How to find the overlapped points using query in postgresql?

Comment: Can you add your table structure and perhaps some sample records?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two ways to find duplicate records using aggregate functions. Assume a table `my_table` with geometry column `geom` and primary key `gid`:

First, using a `HAVING` statement, and collecting the primary keys with `array_agg`:

```
SELECT array_agg(gid), count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY geom
HAVING count(gid) > 1;
```

Second, using a `WINDOW` to count the partitions.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT gid, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY geom)
  FROM my_table
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE count > 1;
```